# When user decline permission for FB login, it shows "fb_exchange_token parameter not specified"

Tags: php, facebook, oauth, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-login

I am using FB login php sdk for oauth login. When given user permissions and login functionality, it works. But if the user declines the permission for retrieving the user data, it shows a blank page with "fb_exchange_token parameter not specified". How can I solve this?

```
require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/facebook-sdk-v5/autoload.php';

$fb = new Facebook\Facebook([
  'app_id' => 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
  'app_secret' => 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
  'default_graph_version' => 'v2.4',
  ]);

$permissions = ['public_profile,email,user_about_me,user_friends,user_location']; // Optional permissions

$login_helper = $fb->getRedirectLoginHelper();

$loginUrl = $login_helper->getLoginUrl('http://{your-website}/login-callback.php', $permissions);
```

Comment: You need to show the code.

Comment: @MangeshGhotage added.

Comment: _Where_ does it show the error you mentioned? And what kind of “error” is it – an uncaught exception maybe? Then you need to catch and handle that properly.